# BigQuery - How to order by event

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm starting using BigQuery these days for work. Until now I managed to request what I wanted but I'm stuck.
I retrieve data from Firebase on my big query console. These data are events from a mobile game we are testing.

I would like to know how many players are there in each level by ABVersion. I can't figure out how to do it.
I did this:

```
SELECT
param.value.string_value AS Version, 
COUNT (DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS Players,
param2.value.string_value AS Level
  FROM
    `*Name of the dataset*`,
    UNNEST(event_params) AS param,
    UNNEST(event_params) AS param2
  WHERE
 event_name = 'Level_end'
 AND param.key = 'ABVersion'
 AND param2.key = 'Level'
GROUP BY Version,Level
```

And I got this:

[image]

I would like to have the number of players per level, with the ABVersion provided.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure level is a string parameter? I'd try param2.value.int_value. It would be better if you can provide sample data from that event.
Besides data, there are several optimization opportunities in your query. However, I'd like to see sample data, first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) 
You're right, it was an int_value! I don't know why I wrote string_value. Thank you

Thank you so much for the optimization opportunity! Levels are a int_value as you suggested. It displays like this: 
1  400
2  380
3  350
1, 2, 3 are levels, the numbers are the number of players

Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Sabri Karagönen could you please post it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Level is an integer parameter instead of string. So you should use value.int_value for level.

For the thing you're trying to do, it looks like a better query to me:

```
SELECT 
    highest_level,
    abversion,
    count(*) as players
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_pseudo_id,
        ANY_VALUE((SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(params) WHERE key = 'ABVersion')) as abversion,
        MAX((SELECT value.int64_value FROM UNNEST(params) WHERE key = 'Level')) as highest_level
    FROM `*Name of the dataset*`,
    WHERE
       event_name = 'Level_end'
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(params) WHERE key IN ('Level', 'ABVersion'))
    GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D